# Is there any program designed for writing a book?

Tags: software-recommendation, books

Is there any program for writing a book? I tried to find it on some forums and sites, but I really couldn't find any.

Comment: libreoffice can do most anything. If that does not suite your needs please update the question as to what is missing.

Comment: Consider [LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX). In Ubuntu, you can install [`texlive`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=texlive), and perhaps [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) if you are used to "seeing" the appearance of your files while you write them. Both are available from the Software Center.

Comment: What sort of program do you want? What features do you need? What were you using before you started using Ubuntu?

Comment: @user169939: Can you please add some information? What type of book (academic / story) do you want to write? How do you want to publish it (printed / epub / pdf)?

Answer (score 38):

For smaller projects, you should be fine with Libreoffice Writer.

If you are looking for a professional typesetting tool, the most well known and most widely used open source program is called [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). On Ubuntu, the [texlive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texlive) LaTeX distribution is available in the software repository.

Beware, that LaTeX is not a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor, but a WYGIWYW (What You Get Is What You Want) typesetting language, and can in some respects be compared to HTML.

LaTeX files are plain text, which are compiled by the LaTeX program into DVI or PDF files. There exist numerous style templates, and with some knowledge of the LaTeX language one can write them oneself.

Using a style template and only writing plain text spares the user the tedious work with layout, and lets the writer concentrate on what is being written instead on how it might look in the end.

Comment: I'm being pedantic but: TeX, like with programming languages, is What You ... *Wrote*.  It doesn't come with a Do What I Meant command to read your mind and fix bugs in your markup.

Comment: For a beginner, I wouldn't go near actually writing LaTeX. Lyx makes it much easier, while still doing essentially the same thing.

Comment: @lonesomeday Everyone starts out as a beginner.

Comment: How can `LaTeX` be compared to HTML? Latex is a turing-complete programming language, HTML is just a markup language. What they can achieve is completely different. The only common thing is that they both use plaintext sources.

Comment: @Bakuriu http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2011/03/08/breaking-news-htmlcss-is-turing-complete/

Comment: @Constantius I repeat: *HTML* is a markup language, and it's not turing-complete. Taken any language and extending it in some ways(e.g. via CSS in this case) can obviously lead to increase its computational power.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I would assume that "HTML, CSS, and JavaScript" was implied by "compared to HTML".

Answer (score 24):

Try Scribus.  Scribus is an Open Source program that brings professional page layout to Linux, it supports professional publishing features, such as color separations, CMYK and spot colors, ICC color management, and versatile PDF creation.

For other ways to install, and [Instructions for Debian/Ubuntu](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Debian)

Or [**Click to install Scribus** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/scribus/)

<sup>Source:Scribus</sup>

Comment: Scribus is very proffesional tool.

Comment: I agree with this. LibreOffice is good for writing drafts, but for publishing you'll want Scribus. I have used it to publish books and there really is no better program for linux when it comes to publishing.

Comment: I think the question is about writing, not publishing.

Comment: I think writing and publishing go hand in hand.

Answer (score 12):

Since no one else has mentioned it: If you want something as predictable as LaTeX, but don't need all of the power (and the complexity that comes with that power), [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) is a great language. It's what's this website uses for markup.

You write plain text and it gets converted to formatted text:

Input:

```
# Title

This is a paragraph with *italics* and **bold**.
```

Output:

---

## Title

This is a paragraph with *italics* and **bold**.

---

Ubuntu has a program called [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), which can convert Markdown to basically any format you could want (including LaTeX, if you decide you want fancier formatting than Markdown can do).

Comment: @moose Yes I know, that's why I said: `If you want something as predictable as LaTeX, but don't need all of the power (and the complexity that comes with that power)`. And see the last line for converting Markdown to LaTeX if it becomes necessary.

Comment: @moose I really don't understand what you have against Markdown. Yes, LaTeX is more powerful, but the lack of power is what makes Markdown useful in some cases. For example, if I was writing a book, I would write the entire thing in Markdown, then convert it to LaTeX for the final draft. I don't want to think about formatting while I'm writing. Maybe you do, but then you're not the target audience for this answer.

Comment: @Bredan Long: I don't have anything against Markdown. I think its perfect for StackExchange. But I don't see the point of using Markdown when you want to switch to LaTeX anyway. And you should write books with LaTeX as the results are so much better than anything else.

Answer (score 9):

If you're writing a Fiction novel, this is an answer nobody thought about: **Plume Creator**.

Find it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/plume-creator/

It's currently the BEST free alternative Scrivener. I've been using it for many short stories, and currently for writing a novel, and it hasn't failed me yet. Plus, the developer of this software is always open to suggestions to make the tool better. :)

That said, Plume Creator only focuses on only *writing*, so you aren't bothered by formatting and organizing. It also has an Outliner to plan your plot, as well as Notes for note-taking and Attendance for keeping character / items / settings data. This structure helps you finish your book in no time.

Of course, after finishing your draft, you'll need to "format" the manuscript in LibreOffice or LaTeX. So that said, Plume Creator (like Scrivener) is recommended for writing first drafts, while LibreOffice for the actual formatting, editing and processing.

Comment: +1 Never heard of plume-creator. I'm heading over to check it out now.

Comment: This sounded like an interesting piece of software, so I went and looked at the Sourceforge page. Looks like the project has been abandoned. No updates in almost six years, uses outdated libraries, and the Web site belongs to someone else. Too bad.

Answer (score 7):

[Scrivener](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/) is an option.  There is well-polished beta available for free on the [Literature and Latte site](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33) .
Because it is commercially available, links for download (and support) come from the dedicated forum there.

As [Joe](https://askubuntu.com/users/23861/joe) points out, "A lot of people on the [SE Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/) forum are very fond of Scrivener. You may want to take a look there at some of the posts about it - and for all things about writing."

[Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/), an ebook editor, is available via ppa : http://code.google.com/p/sigil/wiki/LinuxDistroPackages

You might also consider a wiki editor. One of the [Writing Excuses](http://www.writingexcuses.com/) people recommended [wikidpad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/).   I actually prefer [Zim](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/zim/), a "graphical text editor based on wiki technologies", which is available from the repositories.

The Caligra Suite, which is associated with KDE (and Kubuntu) and is available in repositories, has a tool which for authoring books and ebooks.

Here's part of the [announcement](http://www.calligra.org/news/calligra-announces-author/) for it:

> Calligra Author is a specialized tool for serious writers [....]  The
>   application will support a writer in the process of creating an eBook
>   from concept to publication. We have two user categories in particular
>   in mind:
>
> Novelists who produce long texts with complicated plots involving many
>   characters and scenes but with limited formatting. Textbook authors
>   who want to take advantage of the added possibilities in eBooks
>   compared to paper-based textbooks. For the first category Calligra
>   Author will provide tools which are used in different phases of the
>   creative process: Synopsis, writing, reviewing, polishing and
>   publishing.
>
> For the second category Calligra Author will provide interactive
>   content elements like multimedia, 2D and 3D animations, embedded web
>   content and support for javascript scripting. It is our ambition to
>   work with other application developers to make Calligra Author
>   integrate well with other writers tools like e.g Plume Creator.

Note that if you install [Calligra Author](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/calligraauthor), you will be pulling in a lot of other KDE and Calligra Suite packages.

Comment: A lot of people on the SE Writers forum are very fond of Scrivener. You may want to take a look there at some of the posts about it - and for all things about writing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use LibreOffice Writer. It comes preinstalled with Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Hey, it doesn't have all advanced features. But it's great. :D

Comment: LibreOffice Writer messed up two of my student's theses shortly before submission. I wholeheartedly recommend not to use this program if don't want to get really frustrated. LaTeX has a steep learning curve, but performs perfectly for longer texts. I've grown to be a latex fan during the last year. Plus, for writing a book, you might want to check out version control such as git or Mercurial.

Comment: @biologue That really sucks :-( But that can always happen with any application... Murphy's law. Also, backup stuff.

Comment: @com.BOY True, but if you have a software which saves the files as readable text such as LaTeX, you're much more secure to such a failure.

Comment: @biologue: I've used LibreOffice for years, and had never had issues with it destroying my work. Don't let a single isolated incident make your decision against using an otherwise perfectly capable program.

Comment: @LieRyan Two cases of completely ruined work are reason enough for me. Writing a letter, okay. Use LibreOffice if you want to, but I recommend against using it for anything longer than 5 pages.

Comment: @biologue I've been using OpenOffice/LibreOffice for almost two decades with no major issues. Some thesis templates are even available. As others have said, there is no substitute for backup with any data you care about at all - let alone a thesis. Your idea to use git, etc. is good too, but not a substitute for plain backup.

Comment: Backup is great, but if an application has had issues like this, there's no reason not to warn others.  A good backup practice should be considered essential, though.

Answer (score 5):

Although LaTeX was already mentioned, I think I have to add an answer.

I am currently employed at university for improving a book that was written with LaTeX.

## What is LaTeX?

> LaTeX [...] is a document markup language and document preparation
>   system. The term LaTeX refers only to the language in which documents
>   are written, not to the editor application used to write those
>   documents. In order to create a document in LaTeX, a `.tex` file must be
>   created using some form of text editor. While most text editors can be
>   used to create a LaTeX document, a number of editors have been created
>   specifically for working with LaTeX.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)

## Examples

- [latexexamples.com](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/books)
- my [LaTeX-example repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/tree/master/documents) (especially "book" which might be a template for starting)

  - my [Geometry and Topology book](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples/blob/master/documents/GeoTopo/other-formats/GeoTopo-A5.pdf?raw=true)
- my [free books repository](https://github.com/MartinThoma/free-books) where I've collected some complete books written only with LaTeX

## Packages and editors

See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors)

What I use:

- Texlive (`sudo apt-get install texlive-full`)
- gedit (now, with MATE it is called pluma)
- Makefiles (to save the commands for creating the output and removing intermediate files)

## Why LaTeX is the best choice

- **Typesetting** is brilliant - better than Word (no matter if you take Microsoft Word, OpenOffice, LibreOffice, ...). See [examplehttps://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120279/5645](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120279/5645) with line and page breaking.
- **Text-only**: You only write text.

  - You don't have to care about presentation when you write your content.
  - It doesn't crash
  - You can use version control (e.g. `git` or `svn`)
- **Community**:

  - You get help within minutes on [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)
  - [texblog.net](http://texblog.net/) helps you to learn piece by piece how to get better at typesetting
- **Price**: It's free
- **Consistency**: Your results don't change. So you can compile it on a different machine years later and you get the same output
- You get a PDF as output
- It's old (TeX was released 1978; Microsoft Office 1990; Adobe InDesign 1999). In this time, many developers improved it; created new packages and fixed bugs.
- You can get beautiful results ([Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/5645))
- You can typeset anything (e.g. [Keyboard Font for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78627/5645))

Answer (score 4):

A book is a huge writing project with many steps, each step needing it's own tools.  So it's best to use several applications along the way, one for each phase your in:  1>Brainstorming 2>Drafting 3>Editing 4>Publication.

- **LaTeX** scripting using **LyX** or **Kile** to professionally format text files
- **Scribus** to format Graphical Books
- [or] **LibreOffice** to draft and format in one step
- **FocusWriter** for Drafting text without formatting distractions
- **Tomboy Notes** for Brainstorming
- **Artha** a handy Thesaurus and Dictionary
- [or] **Zim Wiki**, an alternative to Tomboy Notes for Drafting, Brainstorming and organization
- **Calibre** for ebook creation

The chief problem is with the organization of potentially hundreds of pages of manuscript during the initial drafting stage.   That can be tackled by creating numerous documents for each project, for example one per chapter.  **LIBREOFFICE** would handle that approach well.

Some writers have issues with creating numerous files for each project because it makes it far more difficult to move text around among the various chapters as they draft the book.  For instance, if they are looking for something specific that they drafted a while back and try to search by keyword, then they may have to resort to search through many chapters individually until they score.

With a single file project, Libre Office is very difficult to draft a book.  You have to scroll what might seem like forever before finally reaching the desired portion.  There isn't an easy to use Table of Contents for the file that organizes one file into units available at a click.  With Libre Office you will inevitable end up scrolling much more of your writing time away compared to other tools that automatically navigate around a file to specific sections, like a table of contents.

**ZIM WIKI DESKTOP** is an excellent way to draft a book length manuscript, quickly organizing the raw text into sections.  The output can be exported into numerous formats including HTML, and of course WIKI format, its primary design purpose.

Prior to the drafting stage, **TOMBOY NOTES** makes an excellent way of sketching the book and writing preliminary chapters in text format.  The user creates notes, i.e. chapters, ideas, or anything that typed up. The advantage with it is that it excels above other applications in it's ability to search and retrieve keywords from among all its notes, or a selected portion of notes that fall under a user created notebook.  Tomboy Notes can be imported into ZIM WIKI DESKTOP or exported to HTML, or TEXT.

Both ZIM WIKI and TOMBOY NOTES are fairly distraction free compared to heavy weight applications like Libre Office.

**FocusWriter** is designed specifically to eliminate distractions.  The application can takes up the entire screen and has a foreground (page) and background (frame around the page).  A menu pops up at the top of the screen when moused over.  When mousing over the bottom of the screen the writing goals pop up, such as the percentage of words per day completed.  A timer can be set also.  When mousing over the left edge of the screen a table of scenes list pops up, to easily navigate from among those defined, making navigation around a lengthy document possible. There is also spell check, as is the case with all the other programs I've mentioned in this post.

Another handy tool is **ARTHA**  It's a powerful thesaurus and dictionary that automatically pops up on any word highlighted on any of the programs mentioned.  The user simply presses ctrl-alt-W or the tool gives definitions, alternatives, relatives, and antonyms to the highlighted word.  The user can also redefine the ctrl-key activator to anything that suits their taste.

After the manuscript for the book is drafted, it has to be formatted for printing.

Publishers frequently require submittal in RTF or DOC format, then they use this to generate their own proprietary format that they print to paper on.  The specified DOC or RTF formats have to be rigorously adhered to else the publishers will reject them outright.  Still, It's worth reiterating that this is just a preliminary format, not the format the book itself will be printed to paper directly from.

If you are self publishing, then ebook formats are a frequent focus.  HTML is the best format to export to because it can easily be converted to popular ebook formats such as epub and mobi, by a third party vendor who offers the service of ebook publication.  Also, the **CALLIBRE** application can easily convert html formats to epub and mobi since  all three are essentially markup language formats, designed for indefinite viewing dimensions.  (Various ebook reader sizes, or monitors)

If you are printing your own books to paper, then **LyX (an application that uses LaTeX TeX for formatting)** is a method that's popular, at least in the academic world, and for thesis papers.  An alternative to the complex LyX application is to use a much simpler LaTeX editor, like **Kile**.  You can write a book in plain text, then you can use a customized LaTeX template with /input{chapterFile} statements to "bring in" the chapters. You can automatically format a book to see it's progress whenever you like.  What I've done is actually use LyX to develop a LaTeX template, then export the LyX template out for usage with the much simpler Kile Program, and whenever I get anxious to "see the book" I switch from my FocusWriter to Kile and press a button to generate my book.pdf file.  It's beautiful!!

A master of LaTeX can craft a book in simple text, than automatically have LyX or Kile mark it up for Fancy Book output, and do this all with minimal fuss, letting the program handle all the formatting specifics and keeping it out of sight, out of mind to the author. That is a markup approach. You could even get a LaTeX/TeX developer help you develop a template.  Just tell them that the only thing you want to have to do add the proper chapterfile names in the \input{someChapterFile} commands, and perhaps create a few special markup commands for repeated formatting themes inside your book, like for instance if you have inset poems, letters, clips, or scenebreaks, or special chapter starting text formats.  And then, your chapter text files would be all text, except for a rare markup commands, perhaps something like \being{aPoem} to start a new formatting environment, followed by \end{aPoem} to end that special format and restart the default.  LaTeX can be just that easy if you have someone help you setup a template.

For graphical books, final formatting and layout can be done with **SCRIBUS** which offers a true What You See is What You Get approach.  A master of Scribus can craft unique books with lots of graphics, and do this artistically as she sees fit, seeing the exact final output on screen as they edit, and do this more effectively than with a traditional word processor like Libre Office, or a non traditional markup "document" processor like LyX.

All of those final formatting methods will require a significant learning curve to master, but they can offer special advantages.

The key is taking the time, LOTS of time, to learn those tools.  **LibreOffice** can also format a final draft of a book for final print to paper.  Its easy to start, but still takes quite some time to discover all its capibilites.  Prepare to also have learning time with this application.  Hopefully you've got a first draft done else the learning phase could be a major distraction from the creative writing process.   Still, the hurdle of success is stepped much lower with Libre Office than with LyX or Scribus.  Prepare time for any of these, though, to vent from software frustrations as you learn.

Lastly, **Calligra Suit with Calligra Author** was in fast paced development (not to be confused with Calibre for ebook creation and management). It's an alternative to LibreOffice.  In addition to the word processor, Calligra Words, it offers an additional tool called Calligra Author that focuses on distraction free writing, organizing and easy ebook exporting directly into the ebook formats: epub and mobi.  After a spurt of development, in 2014 the Calligra Author tool seemed to have slowed down, but it's worth keeping track of.  When their project finally reaches fruition it should become an extremely powerful tool. But until then, I'm still waiting.

***--SOFTWARE INSTALLATION NOTE--***
I use the Software Center in Kubuntu to install all the software mentioned except **LaTeX**.  For that, I want to make sure I get the FULL INSTALLATION of fonts etc.  (the default installation in particularly limited)  So, instead I recommend opening a terminal window to download from the command line.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: Could you add ways to get hold of each program you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

While LaTeX certainly is a major player here, I really like

### [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/)

It's mainly used for writing documentation for open source projects to be published as static HTML. However, it's also possible to write a book with it.

It's *not* WYSIWYG, but works much like LaTeX. The markup it uses is Restructured Text (commonly used) or Markdown if you want. It is a bit easier and has less features. I also think it's a lot more flexible with the use of extensions, custom generators, etc.

Here's an example book (randomly chosen from [Books Produced by Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/examples.html#books-produced-using-sphinx)): [Theoretical Physics Reference](http://theoretical-physics.net/) 0.1 (1st-edition) (options: [html](http://theoretical-physics.net/0.1/index.html), [pdf](http://theoretical-physics.net/0.1/theoretical-physics.pdf), [book](http://www.lulu.com/product/hardcover/theoretical-physics-reference/11612144), [source](http://github.com/certik/theoretical-physics/tree/1st-edition), [blog post](http://ondrejcertik.blogspot.com/2010/07/theoretical-physics-reference-book.html))

Comment: I've used sphinx for some of my documentation -- I like it a lot.  Since it is closely associated with python, there are also a number of users you'll find on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

[**focuswriter**](http://gottcode.org/focuswriter/)

[image: focus-writer]

> Focuswriter is a fullscreen writing program designed to be distraction
>   free. You can customize your environment by changing the font, colors,
>   and background image to add ambiance. FocusWriter features an
>   on-the-fly updating wordcount, optional auto-save, optional daily
>   goals, and toolbars that hide away to allow you to focus more clearly.
>   Additionally, when you open the program your current work in progress
>   will automatically load and position you at the end of your document,
>   so that you can immediately jump back in.

**Features**:

- TXT, basic RTF, and basic ODT file support
- Timers and alarms
- Daily goals
- Fully customizable themes
- Typewriter sound effects (optional)
- Auto-save (optional)
- Live statistics (optional)
- Spell-checking (optional)
- Multi-document support
- Sessions
- Portable mode (optional)
- Translated into over 20 languages

**Install**:

```
sudo apt-get install focuswriter
```

If you wish the latest version then you can just add the launchpad repository of the project and install from there:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gottcode/gcppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install focuswriter
```

**Further Reading**:

- [gottcode.org: FocusWriter](http://gottcode.org/focuswriter/)

Comment: focuswrite is not in the official ubuntu repositories. You need to add the launchpad repo. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @shivams, I just did `apt-cache search focuswriter`, and it found focuswriter.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I am on Linux Mint 17.1 which is based on Ubuntu 14.04.  Mint uses all of Ubuntu's official repos, so if it was not present in my repo, it shouldn't be in your repo. Just check, maybe you had added the launchpad repo of gottcode previously.

Comment: Hey I just checked it. It is actually there in the official repository. The launchpad repo just provides the latest version. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need to write fiction - Writer's Café is a set of power tools for all fiction writers, whether experienced or just starting out. The heart of Writer's Café is StoryLines, a powerful but simple to use story development tool that dramatically accelerates the creation and structuring of your novel or screenplay.

Find it here: http://www.writerscafe.co.uk/

*.deb packages available.

It is highly recommended and really powerful.

Answer (score 2):

In 2016 I discovered bibisco (bibisco.com). I am trying it right: so far so good. I provide more information:

- bibisco is a self-contained Java application that ships with a built-in Java runtime engine (JRE)
- bibisco is translated to many languages: Spanish, English, French, German, Polish...
- bibisco supports multiple writing projects
- Within the project, the work is divided into chapters, with each chapter divided into scenes, and you can drag-and-drop to reorder chapters and scenes at any time
- WYSIWYG editor for your text
- status flag at the bottom left to indicate the status of the scene or chapter
- define/create structure, chapters, characters, scenes, locations, social contexts, etc.

An example of main menu, with bibisco main menu, with novel structure buttons:
[image: bibisco main menu, with novel structure buttons]

Comment: Can you provide a little more information?  Perhaps a list of features you like, and a couple of screenshots?  It would be very helpful to see and understand more about it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/644421)

Comment: @ThatGuy Yes, and I'm sorry for not being descriptive before. I'm learning how to answer here

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think my brief line does answer the question implicitily: Yes, there is a program called bibisco, which is specially designed for writing books.

Comment: @OwenHines Thanks for pointing it out. I already edited my response.

Comment: @celiapgt after the edit ten minutes ago your answer is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

[Org mode of Emacs](http://orgmode.org/) can be a very simple and practical alternative for document (book) authoring. It can be converted to html, LaTeX, PDF, etc. Here is a short article about how to use org-mode of Emacs for writing short articles: http://www.academia.edu/4005672/Easy_Blogging_With_Emacs

Answer (score 1):

I have a friend who makes her living as an author. She tells me that there is only one program for writing a book: namely, "the program your publisher requires you to use." If you're using a publisher, which my friend tells me is the best way to go even though self-publishing is so easy anymore, find out the format in which they want their submissions, and use the program that creates that format.

That may involve using Microsoft Word, at least at the very end (to make sure that the formatting from Libreoffice or Abiword or whatever Word-compatible program you used to write your book has formatted and saved your book accurately.)

If you're self-publishing, I'd recommend using MarkDown in a text editor, only because it'll give you the most options for publishing formats. MarkDown will save to darned near anything.

Answer (score 1):

Books Writing for Linux

Folks wanting to write a Book using Linux have a good many choices to make.

1st> Is the book literary, like a novel, or is it more visual, like a textbook, or is it extremely visual, like a picture book?

2nd> Who is publishing the book and do they accept a final format version or a pre format version.  Createspace and Lulu for instance require a final format version.  A publishing house usually requires a pre format version.

The answers to those two questions help to decide which Linux software you'd want to use for your book project.

Scribus: The more visual it is, the more likely you'd want to use a program like Scribus.  With it you tediously layout everything page by page exactly the way you want it printed out.

LibreOffice:  This option if for mostly text based books, but can still handle plenty of pictures.  It's the option most Linux folks will use since it handles a broad range of book types and writing styles well.

Calligra is an alternative suite that might be catching up with LibreOffice in development.  Keep an eye on it for now.   There is an application within the suite called Author that's under development designed especially for book projects.  It might be another year or two before its robust enough to benefit from.

The above programs are great in the sense that you can use them to complete your entire book project, both Content Creations and Format Creation.  Those are the TWO primary steps in creating a book.  If you consciously make an effort to break them down into steps, you might have better productivity, AND better content and format at the very end.

So consider using two Linux programs, one designed for each step, for a superior outcome and performance.

A> Content Creation:

Literary text--
FOCUSWRITER -- The best Linux choice for Content creation of literary text, for a book, is Focuswriter.  With FocusWriter you create text files, one for each Chapter for instance.  It's a LOT better than a text editor because you can layout the dimensions of a writing box, and a fullscreen wallpaper that goes behind it.  You decide the font to suit your eyes for Content Creation, not the published print.  It features spellcheck, wordcounts, wordcount goals per day, hour goals per day, popout menus from the botttom (text files for each chapter, for instance), popout menus from the left side (this breaks a single text file into sections or scenes for instance) and popout menu from the top (settings, file options, etc).  and popout scrolling from the right.

graphics--
GiMP, InkScape.  For book covers and graphics.

B> FORMAT for publication.

Once you have the text files created (front matter, the main matter or chapters, the back matter) you need to format them for publishing.  To do that, you can use LibreOffice.  A a publishing house is accepting your project, it may require a doc file, so you'd it, or an alternative program like Calligra.  There are other's as well including AbiWord.

LaTeX, LyX:  But there's another alternative for folks who self-publish or are have a publisher that accepts Fully Formatted pdf files.  This option is especially good for Linux folks who like to script.  is to use LaTeX with LyX.  But, before you do, you need to know who is publishing the book, and the format they require.  A publishing company will typically require a preformatted version rather than the final formatted version, in a doc file.  Again, LibreOffice will be what you need.  Scribus might be a solution for others.  If you decide to self publish on Createspace or Lulu then a pdf option exists and you need a final format version.  In that case, LyX with LaTeX is a good choice, but requires a heavy learning curve that most aren't going to tolerate struggling through.

The benefit of LaTeX, LyX is that, if you have a book series, and it's primarily text based, but can include pictures that are of secondary importance to the look and feel of your book, then you can script templates that will automatically format the text files of you chapters into a book literally a click of the button, with page numbering, hyphenation, justification, headers, tables of contents, all generated nicely to your templates specs.

LaTeX is especially well known in the academic world for handling mathematical formula and equations with spectacular results.  So, if your book is a novel, or something academic with a lot of equations and text and bibliography, that's the way to go, if you can script a template, and if your publisher accepts a final format version pdf such as Createspace and Lulu accept.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `troff` (or `groff` which is the GNU version), the standard UNIX text processing tool. Although its main application area is UNIX man pages, it is more than capable of formatting books.

In my opinion it is far easier to master than `LaTeX` (especially if you don't need any fancy formatting) and will produce professional output.

It comes pre-installed on any Linux or BSD based OS (to the best of my knowledge anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [AbiWord](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/abiword). It has only basic features, but it's a very lightweight application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kubuntu, you can use Calligra Words.

[image: Screenshot of Calligra Words]