# bash: ./name.exe: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions

I want to execute a program in Ubuntu 12.04...but when I type

```
./programname.exe
```

it makes error:

```
bash: ./gbat.exe: Permission denied
```

and I typed "`chmod +x programname.exe`" , but it doesn't fix that...
Can you help me?

Comment: `.exe` is a Windows program which cannot be executed on Linux without Wine. `sudo apt-get install wine` and then try `wine progarmme.exe`

Comment: @aroll605 Write an answer :) But an exe file does not have to be a Windows program. This happened already with DOS.

Comment: An exe file can also be a Mono/.NET program.

Comment: It could also be a PNG image, or MP3 file. The only way to know for sure is to use the `file` command on it.

Comment: thank you friends, I guessed that it happens because my program rests on NTFS...So I changed the directory, and I copied that to home...and now, it works :)

Answer (score 4):

The program you are trying to execute seems to be for the Windows platform. If you do a `file programname.exe` you will get information about the file. Example:

```
file Setup.exe
Setup.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

This means it will not execute unless you have a working Windows system (dual boot, inside a virtual container or maybe with WINE).

This is probably the gamebook authoring tool? [twinery](http://twinery.org/) should be similar and can be used on-line. And we also have this topic: [Is there any program designed for writing a book?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312256/is-there-any-program-designed-for-writing-a-book)

The `chmod` command will only work on programs that are made for Linux.